# "forecolor" and "backcolor" buttons do not appear in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

This is my code:

```
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        menubar: false,
        theme_advanced_font_sizes: "10px,12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
        font_size_style_values: "12px,13px,14px,16px,18px,20px",
        toolbar: "bold italic underline strikethrough subscript superscript alignleft aligncenter alignright forecolor backcolor fontsizeselect"
    });
```

The "forecolor" and "backcolor" buttons do not appear when it loads.  I get no error.  Everything else works fine.

I am using version 4.0b3 (2013-05-15)

Edit: It might be useful to know that I pulling in the HTML via ajax and the JS is within the HTML.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So I didn't realize this, but the forecolor and backcolor are actually part of the textcolor plugin, so I needed to add this:

> plugins: "textcolor"